# How to paste data into a table without moving data?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a program that should copy and paste data saved in a text file (which comes from a SAP system), in an Excel file except that when I start the program the table I made moves and the data sticks next to it.

I'm providing you with the piece of code that I think is problematic.

```
Sub OpenCSVFile()
     ' Load the CSV extract
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;" & fpath & "\" & ffilename, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "text"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 4
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
      1, 1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

I want to paste my data inside my table without moving my table and thus without sticking them next to it.

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Please read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I'm sorry but there is nothing on your code moving your data @user11503878. This can't be the problem. Your problem may be inside your `OpenCSVFile` procedure.

Comment: Okay, I edited my post with the CVS file opening procedure.

Comment: @user11503878 can you paste images from the before and after?

Comment: @Damian Of course, it's okay, I put screenshots.

Comment: @Damian  think the code does show part of the problem. When you add a data connection, other content it moved to the right or down! Essentially, he needs to bring in the data without adding a new connection each time.

Comment: @rohrl77 yeah... his previous code wasn't this... Thought he deleted the previous that's why I asked him to show us this code.

Comment: @user11503878 like rohrl77 stated, your data is moving because of the connection. My advice? Create a temp sheet, paste your CSV and copy paste to your table.

Comment: The other thing is that my txt file doesn't look like the tut to what is copied so I don't understand. 
I will try to add a temp sheet. Thank you very much.